# How can I run a service with regular location updates in android

Tags: android, performance

I'm using `LocationListener` in my service to get regular location updates. When I close the process, the service does not give any updates to me. What can I do?

Comment: Use fused location api create location request  according to your request and that use :-
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates
it will give you location update according to your location request

Comment: fusedlocation is not working properly

Answer (score 0):

you service as a START_STICKY.

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    // initialize location
    initLocation();
    Log.e("", "onStartCommand");
    return START_STICKY;
}
```

It will run in background after kill..and if there is any update of location you can get update.